# Run this Java script code and send me the output

Tags: javascript

Please I NEED some one to run this code and send me the output, because i am unable to run it

package squarematrix;

public class SquareMatrix {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m = {   
                   {10, 12, 11}, //   {1, 2, 3},
                   { 9,  8, 31}, //   {4, 5, 6},
                   { 2, 16, 24}  //   {7, 8, 9},
                };

    int sum = 0;
    int R = m.length; // length of rows
    int C = m[0].length; // length of columns

    if (R == C) { // checks that matrix is square
    // for m the secondary diagonal is 2, 8, 11 --> sum = 21
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) { // iterates through secondsary diagonal
            sum += m[i][m.length - i - 1]; // adds each diagonal element to sum
    } } else {
            System.out.println("This is not a square matrix.");
    }

    System.out.println("Diagonal sum: " + sum);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is JAVA code, not JavaScript code

and the output is:
Diagonal sum: 21

Answer (score 0):

It's output is: *Diagonal sum: 21*

It's a `Java` program and I ran it on an online compiler: https://ideone.com/6KrzGh